# Populating fields depending the json content

Tags: javascript, json

1. I do not want to use jQuery.
2. If possible I would like to keep my `<mytag>`.

I have this type of json:

```
{
    "datas": [
        {
            "id": "hotel_name",
            "value": "My hotel name"
        },
        {
            "id": "hotel_description",
            "value": "My description"
        }
    ]
}
```

From this json, I would like to set the contents the following html tags:

```
<mytag id="hotel_name"></mytag>
<mytag id="hotel_description"></mytag>
```

To:

```
<mytag id="hotel_name">My hotel name</mytag>
<mytag id="hotel_description">My description</mytag>
```

What I have tried already:

```
function createElements(elements) {
    elements.datas.forEach(function (element) {
        var div = document.getElementById(element.id);
        div.innerHTML = element.value;
    });
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();    
request.onload = createElements;
request.responseType = "json";
request.open("GET", "datas.json", true);
request.send();
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "autocomplete"? Do you intend the user's browser to fill those fields? Do you just want to set the contents of those fields to the data from your JSON response? Do you want those to drop-down as suggestions when typing into fields under those tags?

Comment: Pass from `<mytag id="hotel_name"></mytag>`to `<mytag id="hotel_name">My hotel name</mytag>`

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done. Inspect the request in network tab of browser console and see if it made and what is returned as well as checking for errors. Should discover you will need to use JSON.parse()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems:

1. The response is not passed to `onload()`. The response has to be retrieved from `request.responseText`.
2. You have to parse the JSON response into an object using `JSON.parse()` before you can actually use it.
3. Comment out the line `request.responseType = "json";`. This seems to be giving the cryptic `InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11` error.

You want to do this:

```
function createElements(elements) {
    elements.datas.forEach(function (element) {
        var div = document.getElementById(element.id);
        // NOTE: Make sure `div` is not null so that an error is not raised when
        // an unexpected element is encountered.
        if (div != null) {
            div.innerHTML = element.value;
        }
    });
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();    
request.onload = function() {
    var elements = JSON.parse(this.responseText); // Parse response.
    createElements(elements);
}
//request.responseType = "json"; // <-- Delete this line.
request.open("GET", "datas.json", true);
request.send();
```

Comment: Do I need tu change my 5 last lines ?

Comment: So I have this error : `InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.` et this line `var elements = JSON.parse(request.responseText);`.

Comment: @Renée I got it working. See my update (and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t05qxd1a/1/)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>your title</title>
</head>
<body>

<mytag id="hotel_name"></mytag>
<mytag id="hotel_description"></mytag>


<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload  = function (){   
   var json = {"datas": [{"id": "hotel_name", "value": "My hotel name"},
                         {"id": "hotel_description", "value": "My description"}
                        ]
              };

    var id="";
    var value = "";


    for(var i=0;i<json.datas.length;i++){

        id = json.datas[i].id;
        value = json.datas[i].value;
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
    }

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

By the way why you want to use "mytag", if you use "mytag" your document is **no longer valid html document**

try to validate this html document in [html validator](http://validator.w3.org/check)

in the bottom you will get this : 
[image]

***So it is better to use defined html tags like div,span,section etc to get a  valid html document***